# Clearing a string variable after each iteration of For Loop

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

Code:

```
Dim PrefixDict, k, j
Dim renamePrefix As String
Set PrefixDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For k = 1 To fileList.Count
    renamePrefix = renamePrefix + fileList.Item(k).renamePrefix + IIf(k < fileList.Count, ", ", " - ")
    PrefixDict(fileList(k).FilePattern) = renamePrefix
Next k

For Each j In PrefixDict
Debug.Print j, PrefixDict(j)
Next
```

Output (Immediate Window):

```
Sat_Net_Out_PORTME*.xlsx    r10, r20, r30, 
PRINTIMAGE*.txt             r10, r20, r30, r40, 
Sat_Net_Out_OMAHA*.xlsx     r10, r20, r30, r40, r50 -
```

Intended Output (Immediate Window):

```
Sat_Net_Out_PORTME*.xlsx    r10, r20, r30 - 
PRINTIMAGE*.txt             r40 -
Sat_Net_Out_OMAHA*.xlsx     r50 -
```

I am attempting to create a string for each .FilePattern in fileList (a collection of objects) that contains a concatenation of each item's .renamePrefix that matches each .FilePattern

I think I'm setting up this For Loop incorrectly, because it's iterating through each item in the collection, not each .FilePattern in the collection. Essentially, I want a separate renamePrefix string for each .FilePattern. Is there anyway to set this up correctly?

Edit:

Collection Items

```
.FilePattern                .renamePrefix
Sat_Net_Out_PORTME*.xlsx    r10
Sat_Net_Out_PORTME*.xlsx    r20
Sat_Net_Out_PORTME*.xlsx    r30
PRINTIMAGE*.txt             r40
Sat_Net_Out_OMAHA*.xlsx     r50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first loop you can't know when you've added the last item for any particular key, so you will have to add the dash later

```
Dim PrefixDict, k, j, p
Dim renamePrefix As String
Set PrefixDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For k = 1 To fileList.Count

    p = fileList(k).FilePattern
    renamePrefix = fileList.Item(k).renamePrefix '<<<EDIT

    If Not PrefixDict.exists(p) Then
        PrefixDict(p) = renamePrefix
    Else
        PrefixDict(p) = PrefixDict(p) & ", " & renamePrefix
    End If
Next k

For Each j In PrefixDict
    PrefixDict(j) = PrefixDict(j) & " - "
    Debug.Print j, PrefixDict(j)
Next
```

Comment: `Sat_Net_Out_PORTME*.xlsx    r10, r10r20, r10r20r30 - 

PRINTIMAGE*.txt             r10r20r30r40 - 

Sat_Net_Out_OMAHA*.xlsx     r10r20r30r40r50 - `

This is what happens with that code. The structure is right, but the string itself is still adding to itself.

Comment: God, you're brilliant. Thank you so much. I learn something new every day from you it seems.